# How to check if ember model has key

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember data since long time but I never had a situation to check if there's a key present in the model. Generally, I check if there's a value present for a key in the model as

```
if(model.get('keyname')) {
  console.log('value present')
}
```

But now I want to check if there's a key present in the model object. Any help would be appreciated.

Forgot to mention here - Here model is the embedded record and I don't have a model file in my project for that embedded record (I'm auto generating models for embedded records). So, I'm unable to use attributes or fields.

Comment: hasKey = Ember.get(DSobject, 'attributes').includes(keyName)

Comment: What do you mean by `auto generating models` ?. so is that plain javascript object ?

Comment: No its not a plain javascript object, its a class that extends DS.Model, but I do not have an model file in models folder. Generating models automatically is all together a separate concept, below is the line of the code that does that ( in case if you want to know).
modelAttributes = {
"name":DS.attr('string'),
.....
}
application.register('model:testModel',  DS.Model.extend(modelAttributes));

Answer (score 3):

You can either use [attributes](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_attributes) or [fields](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_fields)

Say *app/models/person.js*

```
   import Model from "ember-data/model";
   import attr from "ember-data/attr";
   import { belongsTo, hasMany } from "ember-data/relationships";
   export default Model.extend({
      firstName: attr('string'),
      relations: hasMany('person'),
    });
```

**attributes**

A map whose keys are the attributes of the model (properties described by DS.attr) and whose values are the meta object for the property.

```
   import Ember from 'ember';
   import Person from 'app/models/person';
   let attributes = Ember.get(Person, 'attributes')
   attributes.forEach(function(meta, name) {
      console.log(name, meta);
    });
```

Output:

```
firstName {type: "string", isAttribute: true, options: Object, parentType: function, name: "firstName"}
```

**fields**

A map whose keys are the fields of the model and whose values are strings describing the kind of the field. A model's fields are the union of all of its attributes and relationships.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
   import Person from 'app/models/person';
   let attributes = Ember.get(Person, 'fields')
   attributes.forEach(function(meta, name) {
      console.log(name, meta);
    });
```

output:

```
lastName attribute
users hasMany
```

Comment: Aha I just read my answer, thought of elaborating but after updating answer I saw OP edited question...Need to find a way